# Restkit mapping relationship

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapping, restkit, relationship

Here is my json

```
{  

     "status":"ok",
     "count":1,
     "count_total":164,
     "pages":164,
     "posts":[{"id":2966,
                "type":"post",
                "title":"title here",
                "content":"here content",
                "date":"",
                "attachments [
                              "comment_count":0,
                              "thumbnail":""]
              }]
   }
```

one class Attachments and one class articles

Attachments.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 @interface Attachments : NSObject
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *thumbnail;
 @end
```

Attachments.m

```
 #import "Attachments.h"
 @implementation Attachments
 @synthesize thumbnail;
 @end
```

articles.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "Attachments.h"

 @interface articles : NSObject
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) Attachments *attachments;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *date;
 @end
```

articles.m

```
 #import "articles.h"

 @implementation articles
 @synthesize title;
 @synthesize attachments;
 @synthesize date;
 @end
```

viewcontroller.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
 #import "articles.h"
 #import "postCell.h"
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,         UISearchBarDelegate, RKObjectLoaderDelegate>  {
  __weak IBOutlet UISearchBar *_searchBar;
  __weak IBOutlet UITableView *_tableView;
    }
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *post;
 @end
```

in viewcontroller.m

```
 RKObjectMapping* attachmentsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Attachments class]];
 [attachmentsMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"thumbnail", @"thumbnail", nil];

 RKObjectMapping *postMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[articles class]];
 [postMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"title",@"title",@"date",@"date",nil];

 [postMapping mapKeyPath:@"attachments" toRelationship:@"attachments" withMapping:attachmentsMapping];    
 [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:postMapping forKeyPath:@"posts"];

 [self searchRequest];



- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {

   NSLog(@"objects[%d]", [objects count]);
  [posts removeAllObjects];
  for (articles *t in objects) {
    [posts addObject:t];
     }
   [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

i get this error

> [RKObjectMappingOperation transformValue:atKeyPath:toType:] Failed
>   transformation of value at keyPath 'attachments'. No strategy for
>   transforming from '__NSArrayM' to 'Attachments'

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Attachments *attachments;
```

To

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *attachments;
```

The relationship mapping returns an array of data, even if there's only one.